# Остаток от деления числа в большой степени

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Как можно быстро вычислить (x^n)mod y.
Уже когда-то копал этот вопрос и обнаружил [*теорему Эйлера* (теория чисел)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)).

**Не относится к вопросу:**
Но вся проблема в том, что я учусь в школе, и мы не проходили еще подобных выражений, найденных мною на wiki, и теории чисел.

---

Объясните пожалуйста:

- Как использовать эту теорему на практике(например, реализация на C).
- (Не так важно, но просто интересно)Кратко значение формулировки на
  wiki. Буду рад какой-нибудь статье, etc для тех, кто еще не знаком с 
  теорией чисел и математикой >9 классов.

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем вам теорема Эйлера для вычисления (x^n)mod y. Если n не бешено огромное, то просто делаем цикл `x %= y; p = 1; for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) p = (p*x)%y;`. Если большое - то вместо простого умножения пользуемся [быстрым возведением в степень](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)

Comment: @Harry кроме быстрого умножения, дорогую операцию вычисления остатка от деления можно производить после цикла

Comment: Этот способ тоже подойдет, но было интересно узнать как сделать это с помощью указанной теоремы.

Comment: @ampawd После цикла может оказаться слишком поздно - если x^n на много порядков превысит предельное значение для данного типа.

Comment: @Harry какого типа ?? в вопросе ничего не говорится о порядках чисел, но раз уж так то даже если всего несколько раз вычислять `mod` в цикле а не на каждой итерации, то это было бы нелохой оптимизацией

Comment: На практике, готовыми реализациями пользуются. К примеру, на Питоне: `pow(7, 222, 10)`

Comment: @ampawd Ну попробуйте, напишите, а потом сравним произвоительность. Практика - критерий истины :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В [украинской (также как и в английской и немецкой [остальные не проверял]) версии википедии есть хороший пример использования Теоремы Эйлера](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%95%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)):

> Наприклад ми хочемо обчислити 7<sup>222</sup> (mod 10). Маємо, що 7 і 10 є
> взаємно простими і `φ(10) = 4`. Одже згідно з теоремою Ейлера 7<sup>4</sup> ≡ 1 (mod 10) і як наслідок
>
> 7<sup>222</sup> ≡ 7<sup>4x55 + 2</sup> ≡ (7<sup>4</sup>)<sup>55</sup> x 7<sup>2</sup> ≡ 1<sup>55</sup> x 7<sup>2</sup> ≡ 49 ≡ 9 (mod 10).

Моя попытка перевода:

Например мы хотим вычислить "7<sup>222</sup> (mod 10)". `7` и `10` являются взаимно-простыми и `φ(10) = 4` (это число натуральных чисел не больших чем `10` и являющихся взаимнопростыми по отношению к `10`. Это следующие числа: 1,3,7,9 и всего их `4`).

Следовательно согласно теореме Эйлера  7<sup>4</sup> ≡ 1 (mod 10) и как следствие:

7<sup>222</sup> ≡ 7<sup>4x55 + 2</sup> ≡ (7<sup>4</sup>)<sup>55</sup> x 7<sup>2</sup> ≡ 1<sup>55</sup> x 7<sup>2</sup> ≡ 49 ≡ 9 (mod 10).

Следствия из теоремы:

если a<sup>φ(n)</sup> ≡ 1 (mod n), то и (a<sup>φ(n)</sup>)<sup>k</sup> ≡ 1 (mod n) для любого положительного `k`, т.к.

(a<sup>φ(n)</sup>)<sup>k</sup> ≡ a<sup>φ(n)</sup> mod n * (a<sup>φ(n)</sup>)<sup>k - 1</sup> mod n ≡ (a<sup>φ(n)</sup>)<sup>k - 1</sup> (mod n) и т.д.

Comment: Немецкой статьи нет в википедии, да и зачем было переводить, если в [русской версии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)) это всё уже написано?